# Expandable\accordion table row example

Tags: tables, grid, accordion

I would like to to present the users with a set of data, in a table\grid and when they click on a row, instead of taking them to another page with a form, to expand the row (like accordion) and show more information. This is not typical accordion design as I would like to put more than one data item in the header. Do you have any good example where this was done?

Comment: Hi Dina, your question requires more google fu and less UX to answer it. If you want to get feedback on your design you can provide some mockups.

Comment: ..and to provide mockups you could use the famous tools used here or see if this helps : http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=accordionPanelBean